# Charles Proxy 100% throttling

Tags: ios, charles-proxy, bandwidth-throttling

I'm using Charles (4.0.2) as a proxy server to test my mobile app, which relies on WebSockets inside of a WKWebView.  I am trying to simulate a situation in which a user briefly experiences no packet movement on their internet connection (about 5 seconds of 0 packets up or down).  Here are my throttle settings:

[image]

I can't imagine how I could possibly throttle things more... yet it seems to have zero effect.  The data is still moving up and down the web socket.  Any idea how I can 100% throttle my connection?

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>Network Link Conditioner</kbd> iphone's setting:

`Setting` -> `Developer` -> `Network Link Conditioner` -> `Status`

[image]

Choose a profile (in your case 100% Loss seem appropriate) and enable its.

Comment: I'd love to do that, but I can't connect switch out of my app for this test

Comment: what do you mean about "I can't connect switch out of my app for this test" ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I can't context switch from my app to the link conditioner settings. The test is good connection -> 5 seconds of no connection -> good connection again, without leaving the app

Comment: How about turn your iPhone or your mac into a Wifi hotspot, when you want no network connection , simply disconnect your mac or iphone from wifi.